# React private Route infinite render - Getting error Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render my components inside private routes if the user is authed. But I keep getting the error.
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

To see if a user is authed I get the token from the localStorage.

The commented line const authed = true was for testing purpose, and it works.

My Routes component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { RouteWithLayout } from './components';
import { Main as MainLayout, Minimal as MinimalLayout} from './layouts';

import {
  Dashboard as DashboardView,
  ProductList as ProductListView,
  UserList as UserListView,
  Typography as TypographyView,
  Icons as IconsView,
  Account as AccountView,
  Settings as SettingsView,
  NotFound as NotFoundView,
  Login as LoginView,
} from './views';

const Routes = () => {
  const authed = !!localStorage.getItem('token');
  //const authed = true;

  return (
    <Switch>
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={LoginView} exact layout={MinimalLayout} path="/login" />
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
      {/*authed={this.state.authed}*/}
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={DashboardView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/dashboard" />{' '}
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={UserListView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/users" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={ProductListView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/products" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={TypographyView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/typography" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={IconsView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/icons" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={AccountView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/account" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={SettingsView} exact layout={MainLayout} path="/settings" />
      <RouteWithLayout authed={authed} component={NotFoundView} exact layout={MinimalLayout} path="/not-found" />
      <Redirect to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

And my RouteWithLayout looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const RouteWithLayout = props => {
  const { authed, layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={matchProps =>
        authed === true ? (
          <Layout>
            <Component {...matchProps} />
          </Layout>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

RouteWithLayout.propTypes = {
  authed: PropTypes.any,
  component: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  layout: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  path: PropTypes.string,
  props: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

export default RouteWithLayout;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like if `auth === false`, you will infinitely redirect because the `/login` route uses `RouteWithLayout`.

Given `auth === false`:

1. Navigate to /login
2. RouteWithLayout logic is used
3. If auth isn't true, redirect to /login

These steps just get repeated over and over, so you need a special case for the login route — lots of different ways to implement that.

Side note: you have a stray `{' '}` after your dashboard route.

Another side note: You're probably still working through this part, but worth mentioning that this is VERY insecure: `const authed = !!localStorage.getItem('token');` That code means that any non falsy value will be accepted as a valid token, meaning I could manually just add a dummy token to localStorage and authenticate.

Comment: Thank you very much! For taking the time not only to answer, but to make me see my errors. Appreciate it <3